# Como eu pego o PromiseResult de um retorno?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou fazendo `Promise` e `Async Await`:

```
async function doARgraph(){
    const data = await ARapi();
    const doThis = await ARgraph(data);
    return  data['interval'];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    const resolve = doARgraph();
    setInterval(doARgraph, resolve);
});
```

O retorno do `doARgraph` é um número inteiro em milissegundos pra setar o tempo no `setInterval`.

O problema que eu dei um `console.log` em `resolve` e me retornou isso:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: 900000
```

E eu não consigo pegar o valor que está em `[[PromiseResult]]: 900000`, alguém tem idéia de como eu posso pegar esse valor?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117620/discussion-on-question-by-guilherme-oliveira-como-eu-pego-o-promiseresult-de-um)